# How to add outro background music to another audio file with FFMpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have two files: story.wav (180 seconds) and background-music.wav (90 seconds). I need a FFMpeg command that merges the two files and fades in background-music.wav (with esin) 30 seconds before the end of story.wav.

I have this in separate commands:

```
ffmpeg -i background-music.wav -filter_complex afade=t=in:curve=esin:ss=0:d=30 fadein.wav
ffmpeg -i fadein.wav -af "adelay=150000|150000" delayed.wav
ffmpeg -i delayed.wav -i story.wav -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=longest final.wav
```

This is ugly - and it has the problem, that the volume of the first part is only 50% (the volume should be kept).

There must be an elegant way to achieve this in one command - but how?

Bonus question: how can I convert the result to mp3 (with parameters like bit rate set) in the same command?

Thanks for any help!
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i background-music.wav -i story.wav
-filter_complex
   "[0]afade=t=in:curve=esin:ss=0:d=30,adelay=150000|150000[bg];
    [1]volume=2[fg];
    [bg][fg]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest"
-b:a 128k final.mp3
```

Comment: That looks very good, thanks! However, it doubles the volume of both files, so the background music is too loud now. The volume=2 should only be executed on the first file.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! And I actually understand FFMpeg now (a little better).